# Get incomplete word matched with regular expression

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a text and I need to find words which begens with one word, and I need to get the complete word which match with this expression.

Example:
I search `"abc"` in a text like: `"Hi abc is abc123"` and I need to get an array with: `[0] = "abc" and [1] = "abc123"` because both match with my expresion `"abc"`.

I have this code:

```
$words = [];
    foreach($items as $i){
        $text = $l->getText();
        preg_match('*'."#".$q.'*', $text, $words[]);
    }
```

But I get always `[0] = "abc" and [1] = "abc"`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Regular expresson to find: 'abc', followed by any 
//characters, until a whitespace character
$re = "/(abc[^\\s]*)/"; 

//String to search
$str = "Hi abc is abc123"; 

//Find all matches (/g)
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

//Show matches in array
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Will output:

> Array ( [0] => abc [1] => abc123 )

Comment: Thanks, works fine but I don't know why I get my array with values duplied